# Eclipse logical directory grouping

Tags: eclipse, ide, jakarta-ee, maven-3

Is there any way, with the Eclipse IDE, to have a "master" folder containing several related projects?

The reason I want this is because I have several Maven webapps.  With Maven it is convention to have a "master" project which builds all the dependent projects.  Without the ability to logically group these projects in Eclipse my project structure looks something like this:

```
--master-proj1
--proj1-core
--proj1-dep
--master-proj2
--proj2-core
--proj2-dep
```

And of course these will be sorted alphabetically making it even worse.  I'd rather have a couple folder where I can store each project:

```
--project1
  --master
  --core
  --dep
--project2
  --master
  --core
  --dep
```

Is this possible?

Comment: i don't really underatand the issue.  you can have the maven project actually stored in your file system as as a master project with subprojects, and then import the sub projects individually into your workspace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create working sets for your top-level groups like `project1` and `project2` (*Package Explorer View Menu* -- little triangle in the upper right corner > *Configure Working Sets...*), configure the package explorer to view these as top-level elements (*Package Explorer View Menu* > *Top Level Elements* > *Working Sets*), and add the dependent projects into them (using drag and drop or *Configure Working Sets...*).

Answer (score 9):

A Workspace is considered to be a logical grouping of many related projects.
Right now i have 3 workspaces, one for a work in Python, one for a work with Servlets, and a "playground" :-)

Any time i run out of ideas for one work, i go File -> Switch Workspace, and do the other.